# Python: how to remove all the packages from the defaults channel?

Tags: python, conda

I made some mistakes and I would like to keep only the packeges I installed trough `conda-forge` and remove the `defaults` ones. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Undo Installation

> *I made some mistakes*

If it was a recent install, then roll back using revisions. Find the revision you'd like to roll back to:

```
conda list --revisions
# let's say 'n' is the one
```

then execute the change:

```
conda install --revision n
```

---

### Migrating All Existing

If you simply want to reinstall all existing packages from `conda-forge`, you can do this by running

```
conda install -c conda-forge --override-channels --file <(conda list)
```

in your activated env.

---

### Remove All `defaults` with No Reinstall

This a little more complicated, but can be done by getting a list of the packages that came from `defaults` specifically and then removing only these.  One could accomplish this with the following (somewhat convoluted) command

```
conda remove $(conda list --show-channel-urls | awk -F' ' '{if ($0 ~ /defaults/) {print $1}}')
```

Here, everything between `$(...)` is to generate a list of packages that came specifically from `defaults` channel, which is then passed to the remove command.  Here you require `awk`.

Comment: is the same for the channel `anaconda`? `conda remove $(conda list --show-channel-urls | awk -F' ' '{if ($0 ~ /anaconda/) {print $1}}')`

Comment: @emax yeah. You can can always try running that portion, or run the whole thing with a `--dry-run` flag with the `remove` part.

Answer (score 0):

`conda remove` Removes a list of packages from a specified conda environment.

**Options:**

```
usage: conda remove [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-c CHANNEL] [--use-local]
                    [--override-channels] [--repodata-fn REPODATA_FN] [--all]
                    [--features] [--force-remove] [--no-pin] [--prune] [-C]
                    [-k] [--offline] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y] [--dev]
                    [package_name [package_name ...]]
```

`--all`  Removes **all packages**. `conda remove -n env --all`

To remove a **specific package** such as SciPy:

- in an **environment such as myenv**:

  `conda remove -n myenv scipy`
- in the **current environment**:

  `conda remove scipy`

To remove **multiple packages** at once, such as SciPy and cURL:

```
conda remove scipy curl
```

**To confirm** that a package has been removed:

```
conda list
```